# PHP: setlocale() does not work

Tags: php, date, locale, setlocale

`php -r 'setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru"); echo date("F", time()), "\n";'` prints "June" in English despite of the fact that I have set Russian locale.

Why does it not work as I need (with Russian month names)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use `strftime` instead of `date` to format a date taking into account locale.

Comment: `php -r 'setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru"); echo strftime("%B", time()), "\n";'` prints "June" in English

Comment: Set your locale to `ru_RU`. You may want to add `.utf8`. the full locale should be `ru_RU.utf8`

Comment: Check if the required locate has been generated on your server and make sure to [restart the webserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654379/php-date-and-setlocale-do-not-always-work). If after trying this, strftime still does not work.